# Country bubbles are in weird positions in the survey map

Tags: bug, survey, survey-2015

When you zoom in on Europe on the survey map, it seems that the bubbles are in the right countries, but in weird positions:

[image]

I first noticed it with Czech Republic, which has bubble way to the east, but other countries, like UK, Spain or Germany have them in awkward positions too. I think this makes the map hard to read.

Comment: Well, considering the geographical accuracy of the land and sea borders, I'm suprised that the bubbles are on the correct continent.

Comment: This is how wars get started in Europe